# Error using com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource

Tags: java, spring, hikaricp

I'm facing an error integrating HikariCP with Spring's JdbcTemplate.
I'm using Spring 3.2.2, HikariCP 2.3.8 and sybase jconn4 version 7.0.0

Spring configuration :

```
<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
    <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDataSource" />

    <property name="connectionTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="100" />
    <property name="idleTimeout" value="60000" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl"
        value="jdbc:sybase:Tds:${hostname}:${port}/${dbname}" />
    <property name="username" value="${username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${password}" />
</bean>


<bean id="ds" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig" />
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="ds" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Every time the context is loading it throws this error and the datasource can't be created

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ds' defined in class path resource [commons/config/datasourceTest.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolInitializationException: Exception during pool initialization
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolInitializationException: Exception during pool initialization
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:280)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolInitializationException: Exception during pool initialization
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.initializeConnections(BaseHikariPool.java:544)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.<init>(BaseHikariPool.java:171)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:60)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:48)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: JZ0PN: Specified port number of -1 was out of range. Port numbers must meet the following conditions: 0 <= portNumber <= 65535
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.getAllExceptions(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.handleSQLE(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.handleHAFailover(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.createConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDataSource.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.addConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:438)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.initializeConnections(BaseHikariPool.java:542)
    ... 53 more
```

Now the interesting part is this is working perfectly if i do it with simple code.

```
public class JdbcTemplateFactoryTest {

    @Autowired
    HikariConfig hikariConfig;

    //@Autowired
    //HikariDataSource ds;


    @Test
    public void hikaritest(){

        HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(ds);

        assertNotNull(jdbcTemplate);
    }
}
```

Strange part is if i uncomment the **ds** to load by spring) it fails.

Spent the whole day on this. Any suggestion is appreciate

Comment: I see *Specified port number of -1 was out of range.* in the stack trace. Suspect the configuration has not been loaded yet. Your alternative probably happens after configuration is obtained.

Comment: How is ${port} defined ? Did you check that it is properly replaced by a real port number ?

Comment: i suspect the too, but i guess spring takes care of that, before initialising bean, dependant bean/configs should be loaded. and yes all configurations defined in ${} loades properly, i verified that.

Comment: Show the definition of `HikariDataSource` bean that you are trying to autowire.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `dataSourceClassName` and `jdbcUrl` properties are mutually exclusive ([see the doc](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/tree/2.3.x#essentials)).  You have two options...

1) Using `dataSourceClassName`:

```xml
<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
    <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDataSource" />

    <property name="connectionTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="100" />
    <property name="idleTimeout" value="60000" />
    <property name="username" value="${username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${password}" />
    <property name="dataSourceProperties">
       <props>
          <property name="serverName" value="${hostname}" />
          <property name="port" value="${port}" />
          <property name="databaseName" value="${dbname}" />
       </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

***-or-***

2) Using `jdbcUrl`:

```xml
<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
   <property name="jdbcUrl"
             value="jdbc:sybase:Tds:${hostname}:${port}/${dbname}" />
   <property name="connectionTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
   <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="100" />
   <property name="idleTimeout" value="60000" />
   <property name="username" value="${username}" />
   <property name="password" value="${password}" />
</bean>
```

If your driver does not self-register, you may need to add the `driverClassName` property to option #2.

UPDATE:
If you can read Czech you can read about the same error here http://blog.prodejna.biz/2013/03/glassfish-jms-broker-perzistujici.html. Basically, don't use `SyDataSource`, use only the `jdbcUrl`-based approach (and possibly `driverClassName` if needed).

Comment: yeah, i come to know that from readme.md, but why the error or port number is coming ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I added a profile to my Configuration file and was starting spring without specifying it.

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() throws Exception {
    JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup;
    DataSource dataSource;
    HikariDataSource hikariDataSource;
    HikariConfig hikariConfig;

    try {
        LOGGER.info("BEGIN");
        LOGGER.info("Creating DataSource");

        dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        dataSourceLookup.setResourceRef(true);
        dataSource = dataSourceLookup.getDataSource(CO_PARTICIPACAO_DS);

        //hikariConfig = new HikariConfig(additionalProperties());
        hikariConfig=new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setDataSource(dataSource);
        hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);

        LOGGER.info("END");
        return hikariDataSource;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new CoParticipacaoException(e);
    }
}
```