# Spring - Hikari CP failing for DB2

Tags: java, spring, db2, websphere, hikaricp

I am trying to use Hikari connection pooling for my spring based app using xml based bean configuration. Below is my Hikari config bean and I am using the Db2 as my database.

```
<bean id="HikariConfig_UId_Primary" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
    <property name="poolName" value="uidPrimaryCP" />
    <property name="connectionTestQuery" value="select 1 from sysibm.systables fetch first row only with UR" />
    <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="${Jdbc_DataSourceClassName}" />
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="${Jdbc_MaxPoolSize}"/>
    <property name="idleTimeout" value="${Jdbc_IdleTimeOut}" />
    <property name="maxLifetime" value="${Jdbc_MaxLifeTime}" />
    <property name="connectionTimeout" value="${Jdbc_ConnTimeOut}" />

    <property name="dataSourceProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="url">${Jdbc_UID_Primary}</prop>
            <prop key="user">${Jdbc_UserId}</prop>
            <prop key="password">${Jdbc_Password}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    </bean>

<bean id="UID_Primary_DataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <constructor-arg ref="HikariConfig_UId_Primary" />
    </bean>
```

It failing to register the bean, saying the database url property - url does not exists on target class com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.
below is the complete stack trace..

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextCreated SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: {0}
                                     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'UID_Primary_DataSource' defined in class path resource [config/SpringDbContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Property url does not exist on target class com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:278)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1017)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
        at com.deere.u90.iafservice.unifieduser.application.ApplicationRegistry.loadSpringLdapContext(ApplicationRegistry.java:
```

any help is greatly appreciated..

thanks..

Comment: So, what part of the error message seems unclear? May be check valid property names [in the manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_r0052038.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've connected to *Hikari* using spring boot but not with *xml* configuration. See my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50828209/spring-boot-2-upgrade-with-jpa-failed-to-instantiate-com-zaxxer-hikari-hikarida/50830372#50830372)

I think, adding up below property should fix error.

```
<property name="jdbcUrl" value="" />
<property name="username" value="" />
<property name="password" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have several things wrong.  You didn't post the value of variable ${Jdbc_DataSourceClassName} be it appears to resolve to DB2SimpleDataSource at runtime.  Per [this IBM KnowledgeCenter topic](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_r0021835.html), that datasource is not poolable and since you started the post with "I am trying to use Hikari connection pooling", I'm assuming you want a poolable DS like com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2ConnectionPoolDataSource as described [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_r0021825.html).
The second problem is that the DB2 Datasource classes don't support a url property, only the DB2 DriverManager interface supports it.  The KC topic for the  abstract base of the DB2 data source classes, [DB2BaseDataSource](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_r0021822.html), says

> You can set all properties on a DataSource or in the url parameter in
>   a DriverManager.getConnection call.

url is not one of the listed properties, so you're going to need to establish the connection to the dataasource using the hostname, port, etc properties

Comment: Hi Rowe.. thanks for ur recommendation. so in place of DataSourceClassName, can i keep the below property
 <property name="driverClassName" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" />
so that the datasource is poolable..?

Comment: I'm assuming that since the property name is "dataSourceClassName" that it has to point to a datasource class and not a DriverManager like DB2Driver.

Comment: instead of the dataSourceClassName, I changed it to driverClassName - as mentioned in here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31029760/6525686